# Regex captures more digits that I defined. Mistake explanation

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture all numbers with a following format:

1. Digits with length from 1-5(and not more!) but not starting with 0
2. Next goes either `.` or `,`
3. Next goes digits of the length 2-3
4. Optionally goes `,`
5. Optionally goes digits

I have the following regex: `(?<!\d)[\d]{1,5}(?!\d)[.,][\d]{2,3}[,]*[\d]*`

and it should match:

```
7,93
8.32
20,43
100.23
2.800
1.597,72
2.026,88
33.000
33.000,43
100.000
150,000
150.000,50
```

what it **should not match:**

```
7.3.2011 
07.03.2011
3.2011
```

I have tested my regex with a following example string:

```
7.3.2011  zwischen 7,93 und 10,53 EUR Dienstbeginn: 07.03.2011
```

or in code:

```
import re
string = '7.3.2011  zwischen 7,93 und 10,53 EUR Dienstbeginn: 07.03.2011'
salary = r"(?<!\d)[\d]{1,5}(?!\d)[.,][\d]{2,3}[,]*[\d]*" 
print(re.findall(salary, string))
```

Unfortunately it matched `3.2011` and `07.03`. I don't understand why did it match `3.2011`? I defined, that after first `.` it should match between 2-3  digits, but it matched 4. It shouldn't match `07.03` either, because `07.03.2011` has wrong format(what I don't want to match)

Can you explain me what did I do wrong?
Can you please correct my mistake?

Comment: I tried your example and it didn't matched `7.3.2011`. Here is a [link](https://regex101.com/r/LKaAPi/1).

Comment: Maybe you need `r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])\d{1,5}(?:[.,]\d{2,3})*(?![.,]?\d)'`? See https://regex101.com/r/tWP607/1

Comment: I think you are looking for `(?<!\S)\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2,3}(?:,\d+)?(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/YlGWs2/1 or `(?<![\d.])\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2,3}(?:,\d+)?(?![\d.])` https://regex101.com/r/ewJEcO/1

Comment: `.` is a special character. perhaps you should use `\.` instead?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your answer! Can you add your answer to the post and explain it if possible. I would vote for it

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you for your answer! Can you add your answer to the post and explain it if possible. I would vote for it

Comment: @Thefourthbird your second answer is exactly what I want! Thank you! If you want, add it as a post and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude matching digits and comma's to the left and right and optionally match a comma followed by 1 or more digits.

Note that the `[\d]*` by itself does not have to be between square brackets.

```
(?<![\d.])\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2,3}(?:,\d+)?(?![\d.])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<![\d.])` Assert not either a digit or `.` to the left
- `\d{1,5}` Match 1-5 digits
- `[.,]\d{2,3}` Match either `.` or `,` and 2-3 digits
- `(?:,\d+)?` Optionally match `,` and 1+ digits
- `(?![\d.])` Assert not either a digit or `.` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewJEcO/1).